# cmake add_test() with different runtime_output_directory

Tags: cmake, ctest

Building off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21413672/2069064), I have a setup where I:

- have `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` set to `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin`
- have a test added via:

  ```
  add_executable(my_test test.cxx)
  add_test(my_test my_test)
  ```

With that, `make test` fails. I get the exact same kind of output as in the linked question:

> Could not find executable test
>   Looked in the following places:
>   my_test
>   my_test
>   Release/my_test
>   Release/my_test
>   [...]

As suggested in the answer, I changed to:

```
add_test(NAME my_test COMMAND my_test)
```

With that fix, I *can* now run:

```
$ make my_test # necessary!
$ make test
```

This works great. It is able to find and run my tests. *However*, if I don't run `make my_test` first, `make test` *still fails* - it won't build anything.

What do I do to get `make test` to actually both build and run all the tests?